# MVC3 - list information used for dropdownlist is null after post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http-post, html.dropdownlistfor

I wish to show a DropDownList in a view and therfore include in my model (ExampleAddSetupDto) sent to a view a list of entries to populate the dropdownlist. That works fine, but if I have a validation error and redisplay the view with in incoming model my list is now null.

My Action is given below (note: the problem occurs if ModelState.IsValid fails). Also the Action method second parameter may look odd as I am using Autofac to inject the right service into the method).

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Add(ExampleAddSetupDto add, IServiceAddCommit<IExampleAddSetupDto, IExampleAddCommitDto> service)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var response = service.Create(add);
            if (response.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["message"] = "You successfully added a new Example Entry";
                return View("AddSuccess", response);
            }

            //else errors, so copy the errors over to the ModelState
            response.CopyErrorsToModelState(ModelState, add);
        }

        // Some validation error, so redisplay same view
        return View(add);

    }
```

My model looks like this:

```
public class ExampleAddSetupDto : IExampleAddSetupDto
{

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Option1Id { get; set; }

    public int Option2Id { get; set; }

    //-----------------------------
    //now the properties for the drop down lists 

    public IList<Option1> PosibleEntriesForOption1 { get; set; }
    public IList<Option2> PosibleEntriesForOption2 { get; set; }

}
```

My View is:

```
@model ServiceLayer.Example.DTOs.ExampleAddSetupDto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}

<h2>Add</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{  
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Add an Example item</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("Option1")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option1Id, new SelectList(Model.PosibleEntriesForOption1, "Option1Id", "OptionText"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Option1Id)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Label("Option2")
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Option2Id, new SelectList(Model.PosibleEntriesForOption2, "Option2Id", "OptionText"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Option2Id)
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

I understand that I need to return the Model.PosibleEntriesForOption in with the form. I tried using the Html.HiddenFor helper in the view to return the list, i.e.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PosibleEntriesForOption1)
```

but this throws the error
 'The value 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataClasses.ExampleClasses.Option1]' is invalid.'.

Clearly I am missing something here and I would appreciate some advice on how to return the lists so that redisplaying the model won't cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forced to persist the entire list between the two requests, for whatever reason, the best way I see to do this would be to use:

```
TempData["EnterUniqueKeyHere"] = PossibleEntriesForOption1;
```

to store it, and then:

```
PossibleEntriesForOption1 = TempData["EnterUniqueKeyHere"] as IList<Option1>;
```

to retrieve it.

Note that anything stored in TempData will be removed automatically after a single request.

Comment: Thanks Dan. All the answers confirm that I need to reload the lists before going back to the page. Bit of a pity, but that is the way it is. I quite like your answer Dan as it uses TempData, but I may well fix it in the service as I am using templated services.

Answer (score 0):

If the Validation is failing, you need to load up the the dropdownlist with the List of values. Other wise, it will fail.

I believe, when you load up your view initially, it executes HttpGet Method. In HttpGet method you must be binding the Dropdownlist

When you submit page, it executes httpPost method, if all is well, it will submit. If validation fails, it will execute, HTTPPost method, but it cannot find any binding for dropdown.

So try this : In your case

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var response = service.Create(add);
                if (response.IsValid)
                {
                    TempData["message"] = "You successfully added a new Example Entry";
                    return View("AddSuccess", response);
                }

                //else errors, so copy the errors over to the ModelState
                response.CopyErrorsToModelState(ModelState, add);
            }
    else //if validation fails, you need to reload the dropdown and display your view.
      {
          // populate your dropdown again
              // You can add errors list into ModelState.
              ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("What is the error", "Error Message, "What needs to be done by user, to get it work");
             return view(add)
      }
```

Comment: @jrummell: please see my updated answer, for displaying errors on validation failure.

Comment: Hi Hari. Yes, my initial view specifically fills in the PosibleEntriesForOption1 and PosibleEntriesForOption2 lists. I was just trying to hand the data back in the post, but clearly that doesn't work. I will add a repopulate of the lists on an error.

Answer (score 0):

On the get action for add, you will be creating the model with appropriate values for these  2 properties - PosibleEntriesForOption1 & PosibleEntriesForOption2
Since these are set properly & available on the view, the dropdown gets rendered correctly on the get.

Now on a POST, when validation fails, you have to set those properties again.

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    // before you redisplay the same view
    // set the properties PosibleEntriesForOption1 & PosibleEntriesForOption2

    // Some validation error, so redisplay same view
    return View(add);
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep for your updated answer. Everyone has confirmed that I can't pass the original lists back from the post so I will need to reload the lists in the Post action. I just need to work out where is the best place to do it as the code is going to be generated automatically from templates.

Answer (score 0):

The TempData technique from Dan Nixon works once but if the validation fails again, the TempData entry is null. I guess I'll have to reload my lists too.

Comment: Just found the answer to this, put your list of values as hidden fields in the view like this and they will be available in your post:       
`@foreach (var location in Model.Locations)
 {
     @Html.Hidden("Locations", location)
 }`